# How to upgrade gtk2hsC2hs?

Tags: haskell, gtk, glib, cabal, gtk2hs

I am trying `cabal install glib-0.12.3` under my Ubuntu 11.10 using cabal-install 0.10.2. However, it shows the following error messages:

```
setup: The program gtk2hsC2hs version >=0.13.5 is required but the version
found at /usr/bin/gtk2hsC2hs is version 0.13.4
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
glib-0.12.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

After half an hour's search, I cannot find where this `gtk2hsC2hs` is. I dug into places like http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs/tools/c2hs/, but could not seem to find the right version.

How could I upgrade my gtk2hsC2hs? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's part of the [gtk2hs-buildtools](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk2hs-buildtools) package.

```
$ cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
```

(maybe with the `--global` flag, depends on how you want to install packages in general) should provide you with the newest version that should be able to build the latest `gtk2hs` packages.

Since the old `gtk2hsC2hs` is in `/usr/bin`, make sure that the new one is either installed there (replacing the old) or in a directory appearing before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`. A default `cabal install` installs executables (on Linux) in `$HOME/.cabal/bin`, so it would be a good idea to have that the first directory in the `$PATH`.

Comment: I tried `cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools` first then `cabal install glib-0.12.3`, but the same error shows up again. Is there any other reasons for this error to show? Thanks! EDIT: Also tried `cabal install glib-0.12.3`, but it shows `Versions installed : [ unknown ]`.

Comment: That probably means the old gtk2hsC2hs is before the new one in the `$PATH`. Have you `$HOME/.cabal/bin` in your path?

Comment: --global seals the deal for me. Thanks! Maybe next time I should just try to @ you when asking since you answered quite a few of my questions:) Thanks!

Comment: Heh :) But @ only works for people already involved in the post, so it wouldn't work :(